# Strange Android bug - layout reversed

Tags: 4.4-kitkat

I was doing some debugging on my device, and when I pulled out my lead, my whole phones layout has now been reversed.

So for example usually the clock, wifi battery symbol etc, on the top right, but now it is on the top left. The screens on my home screen have also been reversed, e.g.

At present I have

1. screen with some apps
2. weather widget
3. Main screen
4. screen full of apps

But now it is the other way round. That is 4 and 1 have been reversed.

Also notice the buttons at the bottom have also been reversed, the back button is on the right side now instead of the left

When I drag down from top of the screen, to see notifications, the icons are on the wrong side.

[image]
[image]

<sup>Click image for larger version</sup>

I have seen this type of bug before and have no idea what has caused it. Anyone know a solution? I really don't want to have to do a factory reset. And Yes I have tried turning it off and on.

Any suggestions would be helpful!!

Comment: right to left locale? this a custom ROM?

Comment: No it is not, I have not rooted my phone and played about with the layout in anyway as I have no interest in that. This just happened when I was debugging some app I was developing, and when I pulled out the lead, suddenly this happened

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In the developer options, look for a checkbox that says "Force RTL layout direction" and turn it off.

It's a developer feature that helps with testing how apps will look on a device that uses a right-to-left language (such as Arabic) without having to actually change the device's language.

Comment: I had never seen that option before, I must of accidentally clicked it without even realizing. Thanks a lot!!!